# AVAudioPlayer not working on iOS7

Tags: ios7, avaudioplayer, xcode5

I have tried all the different options found here, even using NSData to load the the audio files. I have tried mp3, m4a, caf files but nothing is working.

No error messages, nothing.

This is a new app using XCODE 5, iOS7.

This is what I'm using

```
- (void)playOnce:(NSString *)aSound
{


    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker error:nil];
    [audioSession setActive:YES error:nil];

    // Gets the file system path to the sound to play.
    NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:aSound ofType:@"m4a"];

    // Converts the sound's file path to an NSURL object
    NSURL *soundURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: soundFilePath];
    AVAudioPlayer * newAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: soundURL error:nil];


    [newAudio prepareToPlay];

    // set it up and play
    [newAudio setNumberOfLoops:0];
    [newAudio setVolume: 1];
    [newAudio setDelegate: self];
    [newAudio play];

}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I've been stuck with these for too long now.

In advance, thank you.

Comment: What exactly is not working? You say there are no errors, so what is the issue? Do you not hear the audio? Are you using the simulator or device?

Comment: Nothing is happening actually. No sound, nothing. Both on the simulator and device. I've used a button to trigger the playing and the button goes disabled for a few seconds and then goes enabled again but nothing happens. No sound whatsoever.

Comment: I have also added the following code and still nothing...

AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
[audioSession setActive:YES error:nil];

Comment: In the code above you immediately start playing with [newPlayer Play], so that's not the actual code you're using if you are using a button? Have you debugged whether the button is doing what you think it is, perhaps by setting a few breakpoints in the appropriate places.

Comment: Yes, I did debug and it goes through all lines of code. After [newPlayer Play], nothing happens. I think it might be a Delegate problem. Comparing to some other code, I'm missing the newPlayer.Delegate = self;

Going to try that but in the meantime you have an idea, please share. Thanks for the replies so far.

Comment: Still no go for me. I did forget the <AVAudioDelegate> but still not working. I'm editing the post and adding the whole code. Still lost, any help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to declare your AVAudioPlayer as a strong referenced @property in view controller like below

```
@property (strong, nonatomic)  AVAudioPlayer * newAudio;
```

If you declare AVAudioPlayer in a method, it will be released right after the method got executed, there is not enough time to make a sound .

Answer (score 2):

I tried like this and I was able to play Audio files in iOS 7

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  NSURL* url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"DR" withExtension:@"mp3"];
  NSAssert(url, @"URL is valid."); 
  NSError* error = nil;
  self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
  if(!self.player) {
    NSLog(@"Error creating player: %@", error);
  }
  self.player.delegate = self;
  [self.player prepareToPlay];
}

- (IBAction)playAction:(id)sender {
   [self.player play];
}
```

Comment: self.player is the same as declaring it as a strong property.  ARC requires that the scope extend beyond this method otherwise it gets dealloacted